# Accessing a property of an object to map in Angular?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to list all of the specific properties of a list of objects. This is the code that I have

```
const nameList = this.props.students.map((student, i) =>
    <div>{student.firstName}</div>
);
```

`firstName` is a property of students. The students object is passed to the component as an array and in the component interface it looks like this:

```
interface StudentDetails {
    students: IStudent[]
}
```

This is what `IStudent` looks like:

```
interface IStudent {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    major: string;
}
```

I think the issue is in the map function. The goal is just to print out the list of student first names only. Right now it is just blank

Comment: What does "The students object is passed to the component as an array " mean? Seems like that could be the issue. You are creating an object, but trying to pass it as an array?

Comment: Try a `console.log(this.props.students);` right above the `const nameList = ...`. I suspect it is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `this.props.students` is not an array. If it were an array, that code would work. Run the below example.

```js
const students = [
  { firstName: "Tim", lastName: "Burton" },
  { firstName: "Jacob", lastName: "McNealy" }
];

const nameList = students.map(student => student.firstName);

console.log(nameList);
```